# Force a full preload HTML5 video with Javascript?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, preload

I'm about to try to fully preload a video in HTML5. I use the attribute `preload=auto` but it does not preload the entire video... In Chrome, the video is only preloaded up to 2% and in Safari around 50%...

Is it possible to force a full preload video with javascript?

Comment: Same problem here: I need to preload the full video in chrome.. Unfortunately I've not found a solution yet, I've also tried to use XMLHttpRequest way, but I have not-allowed errors... I hope that there is a solution..

Answer (score 11):

```
function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {    
    var source = document.createElement('source');    
    source.src = src;    
    source.type = type;    
    element.appendChild(source);    
}

var video;       
$(document).ready(function(){    
    video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];    
    addSourceToVideo( video, "http://your-server.com/clip.ogv", "video/ogv");    
    addSourceToVideo( video, "http://your-server.com/clip.mp4", "video/mp4");    
    video.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler,false);       
});

progressHandler = function(e) {    
    if( video.duration ) {    
        var percent = (video.buffered.end(0)/video.duration) * 100;    
        console.log( percent );    
        if( percent >= 100 ) {    
            console.log("loaded!");    
        }    
        video.currentTime++;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. For background loading, just call createElement on the video tag. Also, +1 for Chin-Chan!

Comment: What does the bindKeys function do? Or is that just something that was left in from a copy-paste? And the index var now I notice it.

Comment: @DBS Yes, it was left from a copy-paste, Answer updated. Thanks !!

Comment: This didn't work for me in chrome (stops firing the 'progress' event around 60%). But it does seem to work reliably if I do `video.currentTime+=2`, oddly enough.

Comment: This was not actually reliable for me upon more thorough testing. This solution works reliably in chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23299806/1417856 -- full movie download and loading in `src` as blob.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It's working good on web browsers, except in IE10 (Win 7) i have got One issue. If i visit the video page first time (no cache) its working just like it must, but when i reload it wont work, 'percent' not logging in console

Answer (score 2):

```html
<video preload>
<source src="videoURL" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: Question: how would browsers interpret that differently from `preload=auto`?