# Why is my video full preload getting stuck at the beginning percentages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

My code is

```
    // preload video
    // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581801/force-a-full-preload-html5-video-with-javascript
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    source.src = src;
    source.type = type;
    this.videlem.appendChild(source);
    progressHandler = function (e) {
        if (this.videlem.duration) {
            var percent = (this.videlem.buffered.end(0) / this.videlem.duration) * 100;
            console.log(percent.toFixed(2) + "%");
            if (percent >= 100) {
                console.log("loaded!");
            }
            this.videlem.currentTime++;
        }
    }
    this.videlem.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler.bind(this), false);
```

(Yes, on my dev team we always comment out when we ripped something off of StackOverflow)

where `this.videlem` is the empty `video` element

```
<video preload="auto" muted poster="assets/somepic.png" id="ssvid"></video>
```

and `src` and `type` are valid. The problem is that it's always getting stopped loading somewhere around the beginning. See screenshot of console below.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616236/html5-video-full-preload-in-javascript/23299806#23299806