# Fully preload html5 video from CDN in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari, html5-video

I'm looking for a solution to fully preload an html5 video so that I can play it through and seek to different times without any risk of buffering. I've seen [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23299806/3034056) that involve using xhr to download the video file as a 'blob' type and subsequently construct a url to that blob using the createObjectURL method. This is the code example in the solution I mentioned above:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.onload = function() {
  myVid.src = URL.createObjectURL(r.response);
  myVid.play();
};
if (myVid.canPlayType('video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"')) {
  r.open("GET", "slide.mp4");
}
else {
  r.open("GET", "slide.webm");
}

r.responseType = "blob";
r.send();
```

This works for me in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari when using a video hosted on a CDN. This solution does work in Safari if I use a video hosted on the same server. I found this [Safari bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101671), although I'm not sure if the bug is still valid. There's no mention of the Safari bug on the page with the above solution. I've seen another method which essentially pauses the video and waits for it to buffer to 100%, but Chrome doesn't seem to ever fully buffer the video.

I looked into PreloadJS, which apparently supports video preloading, but I couldn't find any working examples. I also looked into html5Preloader, but again I couldn't figure out what to do once the finish event was fired.

I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but I'm using Videogular to play my video, which needs to be fed a video url. I suppose if I use some preloader library such as PreloadJS or html5Preloader, which I'm guessing would in turn use xhr for video, I would need access to a new blob url in my finished handler.

Has anyone come up with a video preloading solution that works in Safari? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was being caused by the content type response header on the videos coming from Amazon S3. They were set to octet-stream, which Chrome and Firefox were able to handle, but Safari threw a media error 4. Changing the content type in the Amazon S3 admin site to 'video/mp4' solved the problem for me.

More info about Safari and octet-stream here in the 'Known issues' tab: http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls