# How to make HTML5 video fully preloaded

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to make cross-browser, simple background video that start playing when it's fully loaded, but can't find a solution to this. I know about `readyState === 4`, but it doesn't wait until the video is fully loaded. Is there any way of doing this with classic JS(no jquery!)? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you having? Is it a cross-browser issue? Is it a layout issue to make it look like a background? Haven't you managed to figure out autoplay?

Comment: refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616236/html5-video-full-preload-in-javascript

Comment: @Chetan it doesn't answer my question - I need FULLY preloaded video.

Comment: @Quentin I need a video to start playing ONLY when it is fully preloaded.

Comment: have you tried preload attribute @biydacuk??

Answer (score 0):

There is attribute called preload. You can use it.

```
<video src="video.mp4" preload></video>
```

Comment: How do I check if video is fully loaded with this?

Comment: you don't need to check it is pre-loaded or not. please refer preload attribure in this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: Also, IE doesn't support it

Comment: I do need to check it, because I want it to start playing WHEN it's fully loaded. the `preload` indicates only that it should start loading the file, so I need to check when it's finished and then start to play it

Comment: I don't understand why you need to pre load whole video. You can go with autoplay + preload attribute to play and preload video. Otherwise only go with autoplay attribute

Comment: If you are having high quality video in that case also, it will start playing video.