# Do you need to set video.src while preloading a video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video

I was looking at [this piece code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616236/html5-video-full-preload-in-javascript) for preloading videos using JavaScript:

```
async function preloadVideo(src) {
  const res = await fetch(src);
  const blob = await res.blob();
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

const video = document.createElement("video");
video.src = await preloadVideo("https://example.com/video.mp4");
```

Is the part where it sets the `src` of the `video` to the objectURL necessary? I am asking because I was under the impression that simply by loading the video with `fetch` would allow future videos with the same source to use the preloaded resource.

If yes, does the video element need to be the one that will become used in the DOM? Or is it like preloading images, where setting the `src` of any `Image` object will allow future requests to use the preloaded resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is necessary to set `src` to the `objectURL` because when you use fetch to load the video, it retrieves the video file as a `Blob` object. The `URL.createObjectURL()` method creates a temporary URL that represents the video file stored in memory as a `Blob`. By setting the `src` of the video element to this `objectURL`, you are effectively preloading the video into the browser's memory.

The video element does not necessarily need to be the one that will be used in the DOM. Preloading videos works similarly to preloading images. Once the video is preloaded and stored in the browser's memory, you can use the preloaded resource by setting the src of any video element to the objectURL. So, you can create a separate video element specifically for preloading and then use the preloaded resource with other video elements in the DOM.

```
async function preloadVideo(src) {
    const res = await fetch(src);
    const blob = await res.blob();
    return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

const preloadedVideo = document.createElement("video");
preloadedVideo.src = await 
preloadVideo("https://example.com/video.mp4");

// Later, when you want to use the preloaded video in the DOM
const videoElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");
videoElement.src = preloadedVideo.src;
```